# Why do I get an erroneous "DataSet11.Designer.cs" under my Dataset1.cs?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, sqlite, dataset

[image: https://i.imgur.com/szWidzg.png]

After fiddling with the DataSet Designer with multiple Tables (they involve Foreign Keys from SQLite if it matters), I occasionally get a "DataSet11.Designer.cs" under DataSet1.cs (as in image above) after a rebuild or after a "Run Custom Tool" command. Debugging/bulding with that file gives multiple errors of duplication, deleting it lets the application compile, but it appears to be missing code now that was intended for DataSet1.Designer.cs.

Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior of DataSet Designer?

Answer (score 0):

Weak self-answer for now, but it might prove a useful answer to others so posting it here:

It appears that messing with or removing in the Project file relevant lines that include references to the erroneous DataSet11 has positive results, but I'm not certain of exact reasons and mechanism why.

PS. It's important to note that doing a full search for "DataSet11" in the entire Solution does not yield results because project files are not text-searched with it.